# Function that update his own variables

Tags: c#, coding-style, refactoring

I want to know how should it be **tested**, because if I want to test one of them, it force me to put two assertions in each test (and it may grow up).

```
internal class Foo
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }

    public void UpdateVars(int a, int b)
    {
        A = a;
        B = b;
    }
}
```

Should I test it like this?

```
private Foo sut;

[TestCase(0, 1)]
[TestCase(-1, 1)]
[TestCase(int.MaxValue, 1)]
public void ShouldUpdateStatsAndCheckA(int a, int b)
{
    sut.UpdateVars(a, b);

    sut.A.ShouldBe(a);
}

[TestCase(1, 0)]
[TestCase(1, -1)]
[TestCase(1, int.MaxValue)]
public void ShouldUpdateStatsAndCheckB(int a, int b)
{
    sut.UpdateVars(a, b);

    sut.B.ShouldBe(b);
}
```

It seems horrible to me.

Comment: Well, the meaning of "correct" here is broad since you never said what they should do (if they should set the variables to zero if the value passed is not a valid number or set them to the corresponding number otherwise, then yes, they probably work). Also, if the methods tend to grow you have to consider other approaches and design patterns. Methods should be kept short so they are easily testable and maintainable.

Comment: You would still ideally have one assert per test. One (set of) test(s) to assert against A, another to assert against B. That way when A fails, you know it's A while *still* getting the tests to execute for B.

Comment: Kopranb is right -- correctness means that you have implemented a specification, and you have not given us the specification. What is the specification of the two methods?  Once you have a specification then you can write the test cases that determine if the code is correct.

Comment: @kopranb I have edited the question, I hope it will be more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

That's a good way to test it since you should try to avoid having lots asserts in a single test. However, this shouldn't be treated as a rule but rather as a recommendation. Generally each test asserts a single expected behavior.

If you find yourself having to create lots of tests so you don't put multiple asserts in a single test, then it's very likely that your model is wrong and you have methods doing too much.

There's [this blog](http://www.owenpellegrin.com/blog/testing/how-do-you-solve-multiple-asserts/) article about how to deal with multiple asserts that might help.